# Class AB Amplifier - Weird oscilloscope output

Tags: oscilloscope, distortion, class-ab

I have built [this](https://quasarelectronics.co.uk/kit-files/electronic-kit/3048.pdf) little kit for a class AB Amplifier. This is the schematic if you do not want to follow the link

[image]

It works fine, I can hear decent sound.

I then tried to check the output with an oscilloscope to learn a bit more. I am using a [bitscope micro](https://www.bitscope.com/product/BS05/) USB oscilloscope. I have replaced the speaker with 5 47 Ohms resistors in parallel to cope with the load. The voltage peaks match what I get in LTSpice, but I was a bit surprised to see the straight lines on the descending and raising part of the wave.
[image]

This is for a 50mV peak signal @ 1kHz (the maximum allowed by the design). The clipping is obvious when I increase the signal, and the strange behaviour is still there even if I halve the signal to 25mV.
[image]

The device is also a function generator. This is what the input signal looks like (100mV sine wave).

[image]

Do you think it is because of the oscilloscope limited sampling or some kind of distortion?

**Solution (I think)**
The answer from bobflux made me think that problem was in the quality of the signal. If you look at the signal trace you can see that there is a lot of noise.

The solution was to introduce a 10/1 voltage divider (10K/1K) and increase the input signal to 1.1 V. This creates a beautiful sine wave (although it is seems a bit attenuated).

[image]

Comment: Limited sampling speed almost certainly.

Comment: This looks really weird. Can you probe the input signal? Is the input stgnal generated by the bitscope?

Comment: Hard to tell without expierence with that scope. Perhaps try measuring a known good sinewave with it as a test.

Comment: Passing audio though the amp, how does it sound? Is it obviously distorted-sounding?

Comment: @bobflux Done. Edited my question

Comment: @rdtsc At least for my ears, no obvious distortion

Comment: Despite our "good" hearing, we humans can only distinguish +/-4% distortion on average. Hmm is C3 a bipolar (unpolarized) type capacitor?

Comment: @rdtsc Hence the instrument ;-) C3 is an electrolytic polarised capacitor as provided with the kit. It is installed with the correct polarity.

Comment: Looks like in the new screenshot it's doing something funny. The dark green shape shows quantization but the light green trace doesn't. Is it in averaging mode?

Comment: @bobflux The green trace is the input. The device allows you to connect directly the function generator pin to one of the channel pins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Quantization steps are visible in the waveform. The amplifier can't generate those, so they either come from the (presumably digital) signal generator, or from the scope analog to digital converter.

However... If the quantization steps were from the scope ADC not having enough bits, then the sloped top would be flat and horizontal: it would be a single quantization level. If we're seeing ADC quantization, then the signal as displayed has values between quantization steps, which is not possible.

So, the sloped top happened **after** the quantization that creates the visible steps. This means either:

1- The quantization steps come from the signal generator (probe signal generator output to investigate)

2- The quantization steps come from the ADC, but some sort of digital processing is applied to the data after conversion, which gives this abnormal result.

In both cases, this is a measurement problem, and your amp is most likely not to blame.

Comment: If anything, I'd say that the presence of the "stairs" show enough bandwidth for the amplifier.

Comment: Poor LF response, either in the amplifier or the measurement setup. Replace C3 with 1000uF for better bass.